# Aparecer un alert que no se puede repetir

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hola buenos dias tengo un subir archivos que se sube con un combobox el cual se llama en la base de datos image_text quisiera que ese combobox no se repitiera la opcion que pongan en el combobox este es mi insert

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include "conectar.php";
  $link = conectar();

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    if($_POST['action'] == 'guardarRegistro') {

        $destino = '../files/';
        if(!file_exists($destino)) {
            mkdir($destino, 0777);
        }

        $fileName = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        $fileTemp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $fileType = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName,".") + 1);
        //$nombre = date('dmYHis').$_POST['nombre'];
        $nombre = $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'].date('dmYHis')."_".".".$fileType;
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTemp,$destino.$nombre)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images(image,image_text,id_inspeccion) VALUES ('$nombre','".$_POST['imagenText']."','".$_SESSION['id_inspeccion']."')";

            if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
              echo 1;
              die();
            } else {
              echo -2;
              echo $sql;
              die();
            }
        } else {
            echo -1;
            die();
        }

    }

  }

?>
```

y esto es lo que e tratado de hacer

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include "conectar.php";
  $link = conectar();

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    if($_POST['action'] == 'guardarRegistro') {

        $destino = '../files/';
        if(!file_exists($destino)) {
            mkdir($destino, 0777);
        }

        $fileName = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
        $fileTemp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
        $fileType = substr($fileName, strrpos($fileName,".") + 1);
        //$nombre = date('dmYHis').$_POST['nombre'];
        $nombre = $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'].date('dmYHis')."_".".".$fileType;
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTemp,$destino.$nombre)) {

              $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_text = '".$_POST['imagenText']."' AND id_inspeccion = '".$_SESSION['id_inspeccion']."'";
    $con = conectar();
    $resultado = $con->query($sql);
    $numeroRegistros = $resultado->num_rows;

    if($numeroRegistros == -1){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images(image,image_text,id_inspeccion) VALUES ('$nombre','".$_POST['imagenText']."','".$_SESSION['id_inspeccion']."')";

            if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
              echo 1;
              die();
            } else {
              echo -2;
              echo $sql;
              die();
            }
      }  } else {
            echo -1;
            die();
        }

    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: Intenta `if($numeroRegistros == 0){`

Comment: no amigo no me funciono asi era que lo tenia antes pero no funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes es en la condición que tienes después del `select` que haces para verificar si el registro ya existe, no debes de colocar `if($numeroRegistros == -1){`, debes de colocar `if($numeroRegistros == 0){`  ya que así estas indicando que si no hay coincidencias o no encontró ningún registro previo puedes registrar o realizar el `insert`.